# Should I prevent people from signing in to my website twice at the same time?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I've noticed on social networking sites that you can be signed in with multiple browsers or computers simultaneously. For the website I'm building, I was planning on allowing a user to be signed in only once at a time for security purposes. Is this overkill for a website about entertainment? Do you think the added security is worth possibly annoying people who switch back and forth between multiple computers (like me)?

Comment: It's a good question, but not really suited for Stack Overflow. Maybe you should have a look at [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to be able to login from wherever I want, so if I switch to a different computer I don't find out that I'm logged out because I logged in somewhere else.

If you want it to be secure, you can show an alert saying that the same account has been logged in from a different location (a second login), and even give the option to disable that.

Comment: How are you going to determine "a different location"?  _(Note: This is a rhetorical question; there is no reliable way to do so.)_

Comment: By a different location I meant two logins at once. I'm editing that now

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is an overkill.

It is hard to detect. You will run into all sorts of problems. 
Since you want to detect users, not browsers, cookies are out. Sessions are out.

You can now think of the IP address, but that has issues too. (Think multiple users behing a NAT box)

If you decide to check that a user can log in only once, and disallow logins until a logout or timeout; you lock out users in case of a connection failure.

There isn't any security benefit to it either.  Just a lot of irritated users.
If a user wants to have two sessions to you application, just let him have them.

Comment: I think you're right that it's overkill. However there is another way to detect it. You can have a field in the database that contains the last session ID that was used, and have the session ID change every time the user signs in or views a page, but only if the current session ID matches that stored in the DB. And the concern is that people may forget to log off while using someone else's computer.

Comment: Seems you don't plan to have users from countries like India, where there are bad internet connections, power failures, etc. and the same user would have to re login. :-)

Comment: The code I've developed so far allows for persistent cookies to store the session ID, so you can even close the browser and still be logged in when you return. But even so I'm inclined to agree with you. I think it would make it more complicated to test, also.

Answer (score 1):

It's there any added benefit of you're logged in twice? I.e. contests where having two entry points could be advantageous? If not, sounds like overkill and not worth it.

Now, preventing a user from sniffing cookies and stealing a session (and the prevention of it) is a different topic, but I don't think that's what you're getting at.

Comment: A possible example where it may be advantageous to prevent multiple authentication would be the penny auction sites where time and persistence are important. However, I can't envision too many other websites where it would be necessary to put in the effort.

Comment: Actually I was concerned with somebody logging in and forgetting to log out, allowing the next person who uses that computer to mess with them.